# How to find out when Wordpress version last updated

Tags: wordpress-version

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Wordpress site that has been automatically downloading minor version revisions.  I can easily see which version of Wordpress it is using, and I can see on the main Wordpress website when that version was released, but I am not able to see *when* that version was applied to my site.  Is there a way to find this out without logging onto the server to check the timestamp on the files that were updated?

Checking this site and Google, I haven't been able to even find someone asking this question.  (The bugs we are seeing started around the time WP released the update, so we're trying to figure out if our issues are related or not.)

Thank you!

Comment: The file is overwrited with creation date so it won't be the date of being last modified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check the date stamps of the files on your server, using an FTP client.

**Edit:** taking Mark's comment in consideration, it's probably best to check the modification date of the `version.php` file inside the `/wp-includes/` folder of your Wordpress installation. This file should always be modified when Wordpress is updated.

Comment: it is probably possible to do it this way, but minor updates will change only the file that were actually changed, so  you will first need to find out which files were changed in that release and only then look at their dates

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing -- and then I had to refer back to the WP site with the list of versions to figure out which one was closest to the time stamp.  Thanks.